# What do I need to setup a 5.1 system?

Tags: 5.1, setup

Hi guys, it's a quick question. I am just wondering... I have an presonus audiobox 22vsl, just 2 outputs. In case I wanted to setup a 5.1 system, do I need at least 6 outputs from my interface?

Or is there some kind of device that would help me in this situation (having only 2 outputs)?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to mix in surround, your interface will need 6 outputs for 5.1 and you will need the appropriate monitors, ideally 5 spakers that are all the same but you can get away with the centre and surround speakers being a smaller box as long as they come from the same family.

If you are just track laying and don't need to monitor in surround then you can use the downmix plug-in that now comes with Pro Tools 10 but you will hear everything in stereo.

Comment: Hello again Mike! long time eh? haha.. well just wondering, what monitors are you using :)? cheers

Comment: Andres - BBC LS3/5As with an active sub to handle sub 100 Hz which the LS3/5a dont handle. 

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry. You will need at least 6 outputs for a 5.1 system. One for every channel. I don't see any other way. But even if there was a devise I don't think it would be cheaper than just buying a sound card with 6 outputs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!so I guess, if my interface has no optical outs, I would surely have to buy an **interface** with more outpus eventually... 
